# Duplicate ID in After Update Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am writing a trigger to copy childs field value into parent field value. Let say `operational_metrics__c` is a parent object and contacts is its child object with lookup relation ship. Contact object has fields like `lastname`,`driver_name__c`,`vehicle_type__C` and `operational_metrics__c` has `driver_name__c` field. I need to copy `driver_name__c` in contact to `driver_name__c` in `operational_metrics__c`. I am trying like this

```
trigger opMetricsTrigger on Operational_Metrics__c (after insert,after update)
{
Operational_Metrics__c[] op=null;
Set<string> opIds = new Set<string>();
Date d1,d2,cDate,pMont,cRegDate;  
String dat;
Contact con;
decimal avg,nDays;
Decimal tw;
String convertedDate;
String mTest,actionTaken,oAction;
List<Operational_Metrics__c> c= new LIST<Operational_Metrics__c>();
List<Operational_Metrics__c> cUpdate= new LIST<Operational_Metrics__c>();
List<Operational_Metrics__c> cU= new LIST<Operational_Metrics__c>();
private static boolean run = true;
if(TriggerContextUtility.isFirstRun())
{
 run=false;
 for (Operational_Metrics__c e : Trigger.new)
 {
     if(e.u_id__c != null)
     opIds.add(e.u_id__c );
 }

 List<Operational_Metrics__c> opm = [select Unique_Pile_ID__c,Surveyor__c,driver_name__C,u_id__C,Uid_number__c, Composting_Method__c,Pile_Monitoring_Date__c,Average_Temperature__c,Moisture_Test__c,Pile_Monitoring_Action_Taken__c,Other_Action__c,Pile_Input_Register_Date__c,Total_Waste_Input_on_the_Pile__c,Pile_Completion_Stage__c,Date_Pile_COmpleted__c,Curing_Batch_Register_Date__c,No_of_Days__c,No_of_Days_for_piling__c  from operational_metrics__c where u_id__c in :opIds];
 List<Operational_Metrics__c> uOpm = [select Unique_Pile_ID__c,Surveyor__c,u_id__C,Uid_number__c, Composting_Method__c,Pile_Monitoring_Date__c,Average_Temperature__c,Moisture_Test__c,Pile_Monitoring_Action_Taken__c,Other_Action__c,Pile_Input_Register_Date__c,Total_Waste_Input_on_the_Pile__c,Pile_Completion_Stage__c,Date_Pile_COmpleted__c,Curing_Batch_Register_Date__c,No_of_Days__c,No_of_Days_for_piling__c  from operational_metrics__c where u_id__c in :opIds and Pile_Completion_Stage__c='yes'];   

 List<Operational_Metrics__c> dName=[select Project__c,driver_name__c,Surveyor__c,vehicle_type__c,vehicle_number__c, (SELECT contact.LastName FROM Contacts__r)  from operational_metrics__c];
 for(Operational_Metrics__c d : dName)
 {
     if(d.Project__c=='Nalgonda')
     {
         for(contact cont:d.contacts__r)
         {
             if(d.Vehicle_Type__c=='Tractor')
             {
                  d.Driver_Name__c=cont.lastname;
                    // c.add(d);
             }
         }
     }
     else if(d.Project__c=='Miryalaguda')
     {
         System.debug('prj2 '+d);
     }
 }
 for(Operational_Metrics__c ops : opm)
 {
    if(ops.Surveyor__c=='NLDA Supervisor')
    {
        ops.Project__c='Nalgonda';
    }
     else if(ops.Surveyor__c=='Araveli Nagaswara')
     {
         ops.project__C = 'Miryalaguda';
     }
    if(ops.Pile_Completion_Stage__c=='yes')
     {

         d1=ops.Date_Pile_COmpleted__c;
         convertedDate=String.valueOf(d1.day())+String.valueOf(d1.month());
         tw=ops.Total_Waste_Input_on_the_Pile__c;
         cDate=ops.Date_Pile_COmpleted__c;
     } 
     else if(ops.Curing_Batch_Register_Date__c!=null)
     {
         d2=ops.Curing_Batch_Register_Date__c;
         System.debug('records2 are '+ops);
     }
     else
     {
         avg=ops.Average_Temperature__c;
         mTest=ops.Moisture_Test__c;
         actionTaken=ops.Pile_Monitoring_Action_Taken__c;
         oAction=ops.Other_Action__c;
         pMont=ops.Pile_Monitoring_Date__c;
         cRegDate=ops.Curing_Batch_Register_Date__c;

      }
    if(d1!=null && d2!=null)
    {
       ops.No_of_Days_for_piling__c=d1.daysBetween(d2);
        nDays=ops.No_of_Days_for_piling__c;

        c.add(ops);
    }

 }
  for(Operational_Metrics__c u:uOpm)
  {
      u.Total_Waste_Input_on_the_Pile__c=tw;
      u.Average_Temperature__c=avg;
      u.Moisture_Test__c=mTest;
      u.Pile_Monitoring_Action_Taken__c=actionTaken;
      u.Other_Action__c=oAction;
      u.Pile_Monitoring_Date__c=pMont;
      u.Curing_Batch_Register_Date__c=cRegDate;
      u.No_of_Days_for_piling__c=nDays;
      u.Curing_Batch_Register_Date__c=d2;

      cUpdate.add(u);
  }

  TriggerContextUtility.setFirstRunFalse();
   update c;
   update cUpdate;
}
}
```

But the child record value is not updating into parents record. could anyone help me out

Comment: You are trying to update the same records twice. You can optimize your code and make a single update call.

Comment: then i am getting error as duplicate id @tandonprateek

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not just using a cross-object formula field? This seems much easier than apex

Comment: they will be updated to child dynamically using trigger

Comment: This trigger is going to be a pain to maintain

Comment: This is a clear use case for cross-object formulas.

Comment: Did you resolve this one?

Comment: @DavinC yes i solved it.

Comment: Salesforce developer - since you engaged the community and have now solved the issue, please post an answer and mark it as the solution

Comment: @crop1645 unfortunatly we left that poc

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a try with the code below:

```
trigger opMetricsTrigger on Operational_Metrics__c (after insert,after update)
{
    Operational_Metrics__c[] op = null;
    Set<string> opIds = new Set<string>();
    Date d1,d2,cDate,pMont,cRegDate;  
    String dat;
    Contact con;
    Decimal avg,nDays;
    Decimal tw;
    String convertedDate;
    String mTest,actionTaken,oAction;

    List<Operational_Metrics__c> c = new LIST<Operational_Metrics__c>();
    List<Operational_Metrics__c> cUpdate = new LIST<Operational_Metrics__c>();
    List<Operational_Metrics__c> cU = new LIST<Operational_Metrics__c>();

    private static boolean run = true;

    if(TriggerContextUtility.isFirstRun())
    {
        run=false;

        for (Operational_Metrics__c e : Trigger.new)
        {
            if(e.u_id__c != null)
            opIds.add(e.u_id__c );
        }

        List<Operational_Metrics__c> opm = [select Unique_Pile_ID__c,Surveyor__c,
        driver_name__C,u_id__C,Uid_number__c, Composting_Method__c,Pile_Monitoring_Date__c,
        Average_Temperature__c,Moisture_Test__c,Pile_Monitoring_Action_Taken__c,
        Other_Action__c,Pile_Input_Register_Date__c,Total_Waste_Input_on_the_Pile__c,
        Pile_Completion_Stage__c,Date_Pile_COmpleted__c,Curing_Batch_Register_Date__c,
        No_of_Days__c,No_of_Days_for_piling__c  
        from operational_metrics__c where u_id__c in :opIds];

        List<Operational_Metrics__c> dName = [select Project__c,driver_name__c,Surveyor__c,
        vehicle_type__c,vehicle_number__c, (SELECT contact.LastName FROM Contacts__r)  
        from operational_metrics__c];

        Map<Id,Operational_Metrics__c> metricsMap = new Map<Id,Operational_Metrics__c>();

        for(Operational_Metrics__c d : dName)
        {
            if(d.Project__c == 'Nalgonda')
            {
                for(contact cont:d.contacts__r)
                {
                    if(d.Vehicle_Type__c == 'Tractor')
                    {
                        d.Driver_Name__c=cont.lastname;
                        metricsMap.put(d.Id,d);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(d.Project__c == 'Miryalaguda')
            {
                System.debug('prj2 '+ d);
            }
        }

        for(Operational_Metrics__c ops : opm)
        {
            if(metricsMap.containsKey(ops.id))
            {
                ops.Driver_Name__c = metricsMap.get(ops.Id).Driver_Name__c;
            }

            if(ops.Surveyor__c == 'NLDA Supervisor')
            {
                ops.Project__c = 'Nalgonda';
            }
            else if(ops.Surveyor__c =='Araveli Nagaswara')
            {
                ops.project__C = 'Miryalaguda';
            }

            if(ops.Pile_Completion_Stage__c == 'yes')
            {
                d1 = ops.Date_Pile_COmpleted__c;
                convertedDate = String.valueOf(d1.day()) + String.valueOf(d1.month());
                tw = ops.Total_Waste_Input_on_the_Pile__c;
                cDate = ops.Date_Pile_COmpleted__c;
            } 
            else if(ops.Curing_Batch_Register_Date__c != null)
            {
                d2 = ops.Curing_Batch_Register_Date__c;
                System.debug('records2 are ' + ops);
            }
            else
            {
                avg = ops.Average_Temperature__c;
                mTest = ops.Moisture_Test__c;
                actionTaken = ops.Pile_Monitoring_Action_Taken__c;
                oAction = ops.Other_Action__c;
                pMont = ops.Pile_Monitoring_Date__c;
                cRegDate = ops.Curing_Batch_Register_Date__c;
            }

            if(d1 != null && d2 != null)
            {
                ops.No_of_Days_for_piling__c = d1.daysBetween(d2);
                nDays = ops.No_of_Days_for_piling__c;

                ops.Total_Waste_Input_on_the_Pile__c = tw;
                ops.Average_Temperature__c = avg;
                ops.Moisture_Test__c = mTest;
                ops.Pile_Monitoring_Action_Taken__c = actionTaken;
                ops.Other_Action__c = oAction;
                ops.Pile_Monitoring_Date__c = pMont;
                ops.Curing_Batch_Register_Date__c = cRegDate;
                ops.No_of_Days_for_piling__c = nDays;
                ops.Curing_Batch_Register_Date__c = d2;
                c.add(ops);
            }

        }

        TriggerContextUtility.setFirstRunFalse();
    }
}
```

Comment: No use @tandoprateek, same results

Comment: I have made some changes in code can you plz try now?

Comment: still no USE @tandoprateek

Comment: can you give a last try again by removing line "update c;"

Comment: i tried by removing update c as per your code .still no use

Comment: What error is coming up?

Comment: Can you also check if your trigger is running twice or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15630/discussion-between-gajini-and-tandonprateek).